# When did Han Solo and Princess Leia first kiss?

Tags: star-wars, the-empire-strikes-back, princess-leia, han-solo

The Empire Strikes Back has many iconic Han and Leia moments including a kiss on the Millennium Falcon. Did the characters kiss before off screen?

While on Hoth Han says
“Laugh it up, fuzzball.  But you 
        didn't see us alone in the south 
        passage.”

Luke sparks to this; he looks at Leia.

```
            HAN
    She expressed her true feelings 
    for me.
```

Does this mean they have had a kiss before or is it referencing an earlier conversation “       Come on!  You want me to stay 
        because of the way you feel about
        me.

```
            LEIA
    Yes.  You're a great help to us.
    You're a natural leader...

            HAN
    No!  That's not it.  Come on.  
    Aahhh - uh huh!  Come on.
```

Leia stares at him, understanding, then laughs.

```
            LEIA
```

You're imagining things.

```
            HAN
    Am I?  Then why are you following 
    me?  Afraid I was going to leave
    without giving you a goodbye kiss?”
```

The script notes this as an ice passage and not the south passage. Bearing in mind they have been at Echo Base for some time is there any evidence to suggest they were together before the Falcon?

Comment: I think Han would have been walking around the base on Hoth telling all the pilots and mechanics that he and Leia had already kissed, so I personally don't think that they had already kissed.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [canon (Junior) novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Empire_Strikes_Back:_So_You_Want_to_Be_a_Jedi%3F), their argument in the Falcon cockpit is the first time they've kissed.

> *“Don’t get excited, Princess,”* he replies. He does not let go.
>
> She pushes him away. *“Being held by you, Captain, isn’t quite enough to get me excited.”*
>
> What follows is a flirtation that kind of looks like a fight—or maybe it’s a fight that kind of looks like flirtation. I’ve never been very good at telling the difference. Anyway, it’s irrelevant to your training, so I’m skipping it. **Suffice it to say that Han and Leia end up kissing. If that sort of thing interests you, you can imagine it yourself.**

This is backed up by numerous references to their "first kiss" on StarWars.com

> After everything they’ve been through, and all the back and forth, there’s finally a moment where Leia lets her guard down and Han relaxes. **Han and Leia’s first kiss, aboard the Millennium Falcon,** is the perfect culmination of their dynamic up until that point. He’s funny (“My hands are dirty.” “My hands are dirty, too. What are you afraid of?”), she’s keeping him at a distance, and finally, they meet in the middle.
>
> <sub><sup>[THE STARWARS.COM 10: BEST HAN AND LEIA MOMENTS](https://www.starwars.com/news/the-starwars-com-10-best-han-and-leia-moments)</sup></sub>